# How to store three text field data out of twenty text Field in database

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a swing application where i need  to create more then twenty 'jTextField'.  and store the data in  database enter by the user.
in simple i can do that, but the problem is that in between twenty'text filed ', if user fill up only  three text field renaming  seventeen  text field will empty, and null value will store in the data base. 
how can i solve the problem , so that how much user will fill up the text field only that much data will entry  in database.
please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: The ultimate question is: If user only fill up 1 textfield, how do want the other 19 fields in the database to appear as? null? Further more, what is the datatype of your fields? varchar? int? There are many ways to do it, but I need to know more before giving you my suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you exactly know your requirement, and the requirement being simple below pseudocode will help you do it!

```
    loop over the fields
    userText  = textField.getText();
    if(userText != null && !userText.isEmpty()){//this can be modified according to requirement
        insertInDatabase();//insert only when the above condition holds true
    }
```

Comment: how can i loop over the field ? i have  20 text field ,

Comment: You may need to share the code where you have created 20 text fields.

Comment: i am using net beans  IDE , by  designing i am creating  20 text field. and   as rule i am get that value by 'getText' method  as simple as i creating database connection.,now i face above problem

Comment: The net beans IDE would create java code for all those text fields. that's how your program will run. Right?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to insert `""` into database(Handling null values)

```
yourText  = textField.getText();
if(yourText  == null && yourText.isEmpty()){
    insertInDb("");
}
```

So `""` will be inserted only if the user has not entered any value.